# Help me proving that $\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(\mathcal V)$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Prove that
$\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(\mathcal V)$
where  $\mathcal V$  is non-empty system of subsets in $A$
and $\sigma(\mathcal V)$  is the smallest sigma algebra that contains $\mathcal V$.

Comment: What is $A$? What is $\sigma$? Please, make your question self-contained.

Comment: The smallest sigma algebra is $\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$. What do you really mean?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you would like to see a proof for $\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(\mathcal V)$ where in general for every $\mathcal B\subseteq\wp(A)$   $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ is a notation of the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal B$ as a subcollection.

That means actually that $\sigma(\mathcal B)\subseteq\wp(A)$ is characterized by:

1) $\sigma(\mathcal B)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

2) $\mathcal B\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal B)$.

3) If $\mathcal C\subseteq\wp(A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal C$ then $\sigma(\mathcal B)\subseteq\mathcal C$.

Rule 2) tells us that $\sigma(\mathcal V)\subseteq\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal V))$.

Further $\sigma(\mathcal V)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma(\mathcal V)\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal V)$ so rule 3) makes clear that $\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal V))\subseteq\sigma(\mathcal V)$.

This together results in:$$\sigma(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(\mathcal V)$$